# library recognization fail on DPM 2010

Tags: tape, scdpm, library

I have a tape library SONY AIT 150 GB SCSI drive(D81 library). the tape drive recognized by DPM 2010. But when i install the changer, again it shown as a stand alone drive on DPM2010 console. i have made changes on DPMLA.XML file but it is not effective(for example, the serial number of the changer i corrected on dpmla.xml, is not showing on the DPM console and it is showing as a stand-alone drive not showing slots). what can i do???

Answer (score 1):

Your hardware might not be supported by the DPM 2010 software, for more information, read this link:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/jbuff/archive/2010/02/19/is-your-tape-drive-certified-to-work-with-dpm.aspx

Your best bet is to contact the vendor of the tape drive (Sony) and ask for their direct support.

Answer (score 0):

What driver are you using for the medium changer for the Sony drive?

I have seen this situation previously with another vendor's library; the problem turned out to be that DPM 2010 did not like the Microsoft "unknown medium changer" driver. Yes, I know that sounds crazy; Microsoft's product did not like Microsoft's generic medium changer driver. But changing the driver from the Microsoft unknown driver to a vendor supplied medium changer driver resolved the problem and got the medium changer and tape drive showing up normally in DPM 2010.